# Incorrectly printed the stored array elements in code

Tags: c

Here is my code in which I am trying to print out all arrays elements but only the first element is correct. How I can print out remaining array using same code logic as below with least modification such as passing function array pointers as argument.

would be thankful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
           unsigned int dataBuf[30];
}               snapShotRecDataJoin_t;

typedef struct
{
                unsigned int block1Buf[10];
                unsigned int block2Buf[20];

}               snapShotRecDataSplit_t;
typedef union
{
                snapShotRecDataSplit_t  snapShotRec_split;
                snapShotRecDataJoin_t   snapShotRec_join;
}               snapShotRecDataUnion_t;



typedef struct
{
                unsigned int  blockHeader;
                unsigned int  dtcId;
                unsigned int snapshotLength;
                snapShotRecDataUnion_t  snapShotData;

}               snapshotStorageBlock_t;


void VehSvc_UpdateFreezeFrameDatasCbk(unsigned int*data, unsigned int *dataLen);

                int main()
                {
                snapshotStorageBlock_t local_snapshotStorageBlock;
                unsigned int freezeFrameData_1[3]={0};
   
                VehSvc_UpdateFreezeFrameDatasCbk(&freezeFrameData_1[0], &local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapshotLength);
                memcpy(&local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapShotData.snapShotRec_join, &freezeFrameData_1[0], local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapshotLength);
    
      
                printf("number_is = %02X\n",local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapShotData.snapShotRec_join.dataBuf[0] );
                printf("number_is = %02X\n",local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapShotData.snapShotRec_join.dataBuf[1] );
                printf("number_is = %02X\n",local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapShotData.snapShotRec_join.dataBuf[2] );

                return 0;
                }



void VehSvc_UpdateFreezeFrameDatasCbk(unsigned int*data, unsigned int *dataLen)
                {
                    unsigned int j=0;
                    unsigned int freezeFrameData[3];
  
                    freezeFrameData[0] = 0xAA;
                    freezeFrameData[1] = 0x02;
                    freezeFrameData[2] = 0x03;

                    memcpy(data,&freezeFrameData[0], 3);
                    *dataLen = 3;
                }
```

The expected output is

```
number_is = AA
number_is = 02
number_is = 03
```

The actual output is

```
number_is = AA
number_is = 101F9F8
number_is = 42F9FC
```

The last two lines are variously garbage.

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? A fault? Don't know how to loop? Same value printed for every elememt?

Comment: i have modified the code. please see it. Thanks

Comment: regarding: `memcpy(data,&freezeFrameData[0], 3);`  the third parameter is the number of BYTES to copy, not the number of objects.  Suggest:  `memcpy(data,&freezeFrameData[0], 3*sizeof( int) );` also, the bare name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array,  so this statement can be further reduced to:  `memcpy( data, freezeFrameData, 3*sizeof(int) );`

Comment: @user3629249 that's broadly what my answer says.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the correct size to `memcpy()` on each call. You've only passed the number of elements, and you should involve the size of the element.

The first call should be

```
memcpy(&local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapShotData.snapShotRec_join, 
    &freezeFrameData_1[0], 
    local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapshotLength * sizeof freezeFrameData_1[0]);
```

The second call should be

```
memcpy(data,&freezeFrameData[0], 3 * sizeof freezeFrameData[0]);
```

The code now outputs

```
number_is = AA
number_is = 02
number_is = 03
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it works but there is another ambiguity need to be solved. printf("number_is = %02X\n",local_snapshotStorageBlock.snapShotData.snapShotRec_join.dataBuf[0] ); what should be statment if i want to use memcpy statement in that argument. i want to save that value to another variable and then print it out. Thanks

Comment: Ah! We usually say "thanks" by upvoting and/or accepting an answer if it answers the question as asked. If you have a new problem, please ask another question. Adding a trail of continuing questions in comments doesn't really suit th eStackoverflow model.

Comment: sure thanks but still have one ambugity which is related to above code, if possible please address it , would be thankful. In above code we have structure typedef struct
{
           unsigned int dataBuf[30];
}               snapShotRecDataJoin_t; here we have define array of 30 elements but if I put it to zero such as unsigned int dataBuf[0], I still get output from printf statements mentioned in main code. May I know the relationship with these statements. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have written to the first three elements of `dataBuf`, so if you have defined it as `unsigned int dataBuf[0]` that will be *undefined behaviour*. It might work sometimes, never, crash the machine, or do different things on different machines. You can have one *flexible array member* as the last member of a `struct`, but you much allocate the correct amount of memory for it.